# Comparing Dissimilar Survey Questions

Tags: r, survey, scales, measurement

I am hoping to gain some insight on the most responsible way to fulfill a request at my place of work. I have been asked to show a quantifiable improvement year-over-year, by comparing apples and oranges. The data are unpaired - there is no way to link respondents from 2019 to 2020.

A survey was conducted in **2019** to measure internal customer satisfaction metrics, and asked a series of 8 questions with a 0 - 10 satisfaction scale, such as:

1. Department A are responsive to requests for information.
2. Department A staff are open, honest, and communicative.
3. Department A consistently does good work.
   etc...

A survey was conducted in **2020** and sent to roughly the same cohort (all-staff, +/- staff who have left or joined the company). Instead of asking 8 questions, only two questions were asked with the same 0 - 10 satisfaction scale:

1. My satisfaction level for the services provided by Department A is:
2. My satisfaction level with the staff from Department A is:

More specifically, after indicating that the respondent has worked with Department A over the past year, the question is worded as: *"How satisfied are you with the services offered by Department A?"*. 0 is labeled as "Not at all satisfied" and 10 is labeled "Extremely satisfied". All other scale points are not labeled.

**What is the most responsible way to show a quantitative comparison or difference between years?**

Besides cautioning that this was not the intention of the survey design, are there any statistical tests that could be run with caution? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forget statistical testing--by posting this question, you show that (at least intuitively) you understand that a valid comparison of these two surveys is impossible.  Even without the issue of comparing two surveys, the value of the second survey in itself is questionable.  How is a "satisfaction level" defined and understood by the respondents?

Comment: The "satisfaction level" from the second survey was designed to be a proxy net promoter score question... The question is a bit more descriptive than what I have above. After a respondent selects that they have worked with the specific department, they are then asked "How satisfied are you with the services offered by Department A?". 0 is labeled as "Not at all satisfied" and 10 is labeled "Extremely satisfied". All other scale points are not labeled.